# How to check version of protoc-gen-go and protoc-gen-validate?

Tags: protocol-buffers

How to check version of protoc-gen-go and protoc-gen-validate?

```
protoc-gen-go --version
protoc-gen-validate --version
```

I tried above command, that dind't work.

Comment: On macOS, if I type `protoc-gen-go --version` it will return me the correct binary version

Comment: macOS and `protoc-gen-go --version` just hangs indefinitely. Current version is 1.3.5, so it might have been added to later versions.

Answer (score 2):

I used protoc --version on VSCode terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you run into an issue where it says it can't run one of the commands, you will need to add `export PATH=$HOME/go/bin:$PATH` into either your bash or zshell script files.
Restart your terminal and try the following commands again:

```
$>protoc --version
libprotoc 3.21.6
$>protoc-gen-go --version
protoc-gen-go v1.28.1
$>go version
go version go1.19.1 darwin/amd64
```

You can also go directly to the GO dir and run them as executables:

```
$>cd ~/go/bin
$bin>./protoc-gen-go --version
protoc-gen-go v1.28.1
```